# "Unexpected error playing stream" when playing audio from URL

Tags: just-audio

I'm building an application that hosts an HTTP server to stream audios to just_audio (via a `ConcatenatingAudioSource` with `AudioSource.url` as children). For some reason though, whenever playback begins, the application instantly crashes upon loading the stream, even though the file is uncorrupted and both `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers are passed and also correct (revealed that playing the file inside the browser works). I am also aware that I can play a stream and `just_audio` will handle the rest, but there's some extra backend written in Java which I need.

I've tried searching the issue across the internet but found nothing that really worked, so I'm asking here as a last resort. I also tried to reproduce the issue on the `example/` app on the repository, but with no success. I also tried to see if there are any changes between my app and the example one (in the `build.gradle` files or the `AndroidManifest.xml`), but there seem not to be any substantial changes.

Also, the error is complaining about `FlacLibrary` whereas the file I'm trying to play is an MP3 file (hence the `Content-Type` is `audio/mpeg`), also the app isn't new, the last time I worked on it was around November 1 2021, I was using the `dev` branch of `just_audio`. I saw on the GitHub releases that since then the ExoPlayer version was changed, so maybe some breaking change I'm not aware of was introduced?

The error is as follows:

```
E/LoadTask( 9828): Unexpected error loading stream
E/LoadTask( 9828):   java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.LibraryLoader
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.flac.FlacLibrary.<clinit>(FlacLibrary.java:30)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.getFlacExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:442)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.$r8$lambda$UB0XGN4xVYWMpbhQ5lQLSZUR148(Unknown Source:0)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.getConstructor(Unknown Source:0)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.maybeLoadExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:495)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.getExtractor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:477)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.addExtractorsForFileType(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:369)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.createExtractors(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:331)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:70)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/LoadTask( 9828):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Playback
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): Process: com.pato05.url_player, PID: 9828
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.LibraryLoader
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.flac.FlacLibrary.<clinit>(FlacLibrary.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.getFlacExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.$r8$lambda$UB0XGN4xVYWMpbhQ5lQLSZUR148(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.getConstructor(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.maybeLoadExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.getExtractor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:477)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.addExtractorsForFileType(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.createExtractors(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:331)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Loader:ProgressiveMediaPeriod
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): Process: com.pato05.url_player, PID: 9828
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828): java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.LibraryLoader
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.flac.FlacLibrary.<clinit>(FlacLibrary.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.getFlacExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.$r8$lambda$UB0XGN4xVYWMpbhQ5lQLSZUR148(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.getConstructor(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.maybeLoadExtractorConstructor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory$ExtensionLoader.getExtractor(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:477)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.addExtractorsForFileType(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory.createExtractors(DefaultExtractorsFactory.java:331)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9828):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

My fault: I found a `extension-flac.aar` file inside the `libs/` folder, which frankly I don't even remember it being there, and removing that as gradle dependency fixes the problem.
I probably found that while I was trying to play FLAC files, forgot about it and some change in ExoPlayer broke it...